# Suggestions for context menu link with querystring value to NewForm results in Page Not Found

Tags: custom-actions, query-string

Trying to set up a custom action for a library to send querystring parameters to a NewForm on another list using the Navigate to URL option.

Without a querystring value the link works; displays NewForm:

https:///Lists/Tasks/NewForm.aspx

With a querystring value the link does not work; displays Page Not Found:

https:///Lists/Tasks/NewForm.aspx?SelectedItemId={SelectedItemId}

Manually typing the following in the address bar works; displays NewForm:

https:///Lists/Tasks/NewForm.aspx?SelectedItemId=123

https:///Lists/Tasks/NewForm.aspx?SelectedItemId=

https:///Lists/Tasks/NewForm.aspx?abc=123

Why would manually typing in these paths work, but from the Context Menu results in Page Not Found?

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Some errant javascript on page was looking for querystring value that didn't exist. Removal of javascript fixed the problem.